# After opening csv file into wordpad ,i don't want double space in head section after Sr. And don't want space after No

Tags: php, mysql

When I export data to csv file and open file with wordpad myfield Sr. No. looks like Sr.  No. I don't want double space after Sr. and also don't wanr space after No. Code is as follow.

```
    $filename = "file.csv";
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');           
    $array = array('Sr. No.','Name','DOB','Address');
    $header = str_replace('',' ', $array);
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    fputcsv($fp, $header,',',' ');
    $query = "select * from registratin";
    $result = mssql_query($query);
    $i = 1;
    while($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
      $row = array_merge(array($i), $row);
      fputcsv($fp, $row);
      $i++;
    }
```

Comment: This is the third time you've asked this exact same question today..... you clearly don't seem to understand that a CSV file has a format that should be adhered to.... I hope that whatever application needs to read this CSV file can handle it cleanly

Comment: What is `$header = str_replace('',' ', $array);` in your code for?

Answer (score 0):

If yo don't want your headers line to conform to the rules for a CSV, then just write that one line using `fwrite()` rather than `fputcsv()`

```
$headerLine = 'Sr. No,Name,DOB,Address';
fwrite($fp, $headerLine);
```

Comment: I am getting header proper but contents are added just next to header section.I want them in proper column i.e. below header section

Comment: Then add a new line afterwards: `fwrite($fp, $headerLine . PHP_EOL);`